# Start debugging inside a for loop (matlab)

Tags: matlab

I have a nested loop:

```
for i=1:100

   for j=1:100

   start debugging at i=56 and j=34

   end

end
```

Is there a way to have matlab start the step-by-step debugging starting in the middle of the executed code, so you dont have to type in f10 1000 times before you get to the are you are interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is precisely what [*conditional breakpoints*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html#brqxeeu-234) are for:

> Set conditional breakpoints to cause MATLAB to stop at a specified line in a file only when the specified condition is met. One particularly good use for conditional breakpoints is when you want to examine results after a certain number of iterations in a loop.

Comment: I found out that you could also type if i==56 && j==34; keyboard; end

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use dbstop function like it is said here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html

Example:

```
dbstop if i=56 and j=34
```